# mercurial + apache basic authentication multiple prompts

Tags: apache, authentication, mercurial, webserver, basic-authentication

I am trying to implement a basic level authentication for my mercurial repos. using apache on windows.

I have seen a lot of blogs mentioning the steps to implement it & this is how my apache httpd.conf file section looks like.

```
.........
...............
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so

WSGIPythonPath "C:/Python27;C:/apache2/htdocs/library"
<Directory "C:/apache2/htdocs">
    AllowOverride None
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AuthName "sample realm"
    AuthType Basic 
    AuthBasicAuthoritative on
    AuthUserFile c:/hgusers.txt
    require valid-user
</Directory>
..........
.......
```

If I try `hg clone http://my-domain.com/mercurial-repo`, it asks for authentication. If I enter  wrong credentials, authentication fails as expected. But if I enter a valid credential, it would keep on asking for entering username and password...

like this:

```
C:\test-repo>hg clone http://my-domain.com/mercurial-repo
http authorization required
realm: sample realm
user: dave
password:
http authorization required
realm: sample realm
user: dave
password:
.....................
.....................
```

But when I enter the user and password credentials in to the repo url, its working fine.
eg: `hg clone http://username:password@my-domain.com/mercurial-repo` is working.
But I need the user and password credentials to be added to the prompt because the authentication from hgtortoise gui is also not working for the same reason. 
Can anyone please help me figure out why this is happening.

Comment: What version of Mercurial/TortoiseHG are you using?

Comment: djc: I'm using mercurial v2.5.2 tortoisehg v2.7.1 apache v2.2

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something about the Mercurial protocol that makes it require two password prompts, though I forget why that was, exactly.

Comment: Its not just two prompts. It keeps on prompting for user&pass when ever I enter a valid username and password. But when invalid credentials are entered, it exits throwing an authentication failure message as expected.
It works when I enter hg clone `http://username:password@host.com` format

Comment: I have been told that using basic authentication, only hg clone `http://username:password@host-name.com` format will work and inorder to use 
`hg clone http://host-name.com 
 user: username 
 password: password`
format, I will have to implement active directory authentication. Can anyone please confirm this. I just wan't to make sure before I quit my efforts on this.